# Cannot open phone/mail/map links from WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

## Introduction

Hello Everyone, I have been dealing with this problem for a while and couldn't find any solutions yet. I have checked lots of other stack overflow questions but unfortunately none of them worked.

## Problem

The problem is, there is a **WKWebView** on my app which I use to show home listings for a Real estate office. But whenever user clicks on **[Call Agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q45J.png)** Button on the buttom of the webpage it doesn't work. [Only time it works is when they 3D touch the call button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqO9C.png).

---

I have tried adding this code:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void) {
    if navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "tel" {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

which almost worked! Whenever I tap the call button I can see the call pop-up menu but app crashes after that.

I've also tried to configure data types for webview but for that did not work either:
`webView.configuration.dataDetectorTypes = .phoneNumber`